# CSS Navigation Bar overlapping and padding issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, padding

so I am trying to have an border-bottom hover effect overlap with the parent div (navbar) bottom-border. 
I have the navbar container with margin:0px and  padding:0px

Not sure how to have the hover bottom-border effect be able to overlap with the parent bottom-border. [here is what is currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaRvY.png)

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: @FahimKhan ok i added it to the post! (at the bottom) let me know :)

Comment: That's an image, not code. Read [ask] and create a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide your code. then also i tried to understood your problem. hope i understood it correct and will solve your problem.

```css
li.nav-item {
    padding: 10px;
    position:relative;
}
li.nav-item:hover{
    border-bottom: 5px solid red;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
nav.navbar{
    border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-md-center">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Item3</a>
        </li>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: what i am trying to do is have the border-bottom hover effect of the nav-item overlap with the border-bottom of the navbar parent container!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to overlap the blue line which need positioning CSS property changed. If you are only trying to make them touch without gap you may also consider the padding and margin from the blue line that creates the space in between.

You would have to play along position, padding, margin and "!important":

```
.blueline{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
.menu{
  padding-bottom:0px!important;
  margin-bottom:0px!important;
}
```

If you need to have the grey line overlap you would need CSS position:relative and absolute to have elements on top of each other.

Comment: The blue line is the bottom-border for the nav bar (that contains everything) and I don't want to make the navbar smaller, instead just make the grey line (border-bottom hover effect) lower so that it is overlapping with the blue bottom-border of the  navbar. should i add the important the grey line then?

Comment: You need to use postition:relative or absolute to achieve this since these two properties can overlap elements and make the grey line you mentioned appear on top of the blue bottom-border. You may also make the blue bottom border position few negative pixels to top to have them overlap and make sure you set the z-index property to set which one goes on top